# Scale Animation doesn't affect layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have top_sliding_out animation defined like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0" />

    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0" />
</set>
```

Code triggering animation:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), R.anim.top_slide_out);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    ((View)buttonView.getParent()).startAnimation(anim);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            getListView().requestLayout();
        }
    }, anim.getDuration());
}
```

I perform this animation to hide my custom row in a list. But the problem is that layout doesn't change it's size, so it is left with empty hole.

Before animation:

[image]

After animation:

[image]

What can I do about that? How can I change layout when animation is in progress?

Comment: is this in a ListView?  If so you cant really change the size easily. You could try myAnimatedView.getParent().requestLayout();

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. I added code triggering animation to question.

Comment: you don't need to call `requestLayout()`. However, you will need to inform the ListView that the underlying data has changed. This can be done using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You will find some more useful information here - https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/cEoMo5H9v5R